# MSOFFICE MIME type verification

Tags: php, file-upload, ms-office, mime-types

I have the following:

```
$mimeTypes = array('application/msword'); //used to be an array

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME, "/usr/share/misc/magic"); 


$type = $finfo->file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
$mime = substr($type, 0, strpos($type, ';'));


    if (in_array($mime, $mimeTypes)) 
      { //let it in
```

The problem is that I am getting "application/vnd.ms-office" as the filetype for any MSOFFICE file that I attempt to upload.  I DO NOT wish to allow all MSOFFICE files, only .DOC's.  Is there a workaround for this?

**Please note that these MSOFFICE type files were created in OPENOFFICE, would this make a difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best you can do is verify file extension after know the file is a Office document (`application/vnd.ms-office`) and set manually the correct MIME for current file.

If you have access to Apache, you can add the correct MIME in `conf/mime.types`

```
application/msword doc
application/vnd.ms-excel xls
[..] etc
```

List of Office MIME Types (from http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php)

```
.doc    application/msword
.dot    application/msword
.docx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
.dotx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
.docm   application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
.dotm   application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
.xls    application/vnd.ms-excel
.xlt    application/vnd.ms-excel
.xla    application/vnd.ms-excel
.xlsx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
.xltx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
.xlsm   application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
.xltm   application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
.xlam   application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
.xlsb   application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
.ppt    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pot    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pps    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.ppa    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pptx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
.potx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
.ppsx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
.ppam   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
.pptm   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
.potm   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
.ppsm   application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12
```